# JavaFX without controller specified

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I want to delete onAction to dissociate my view and my controller

this is the javaFx code :

```
    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
        <Button text="7" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#Nombre" />
        <Button text="8" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#Nombre" />
        <Button text="9" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#Nombre" />
        <Button text="/" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" onAction="#Operateur" />
    </HBox>
```

I want to associated id on button with my controller

thanks

Comment: I hardly understand what you want to do..... Can you please use google translate to write issue ?

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the Nombre buttons into their own class:

```
class NombreButton extends Button {

    public NombreButton() {
        this.setOnAction(this::nombre);
    }

    private void nombre(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // Your action here
    }

}
```

And then use them in your view like regular buttons.

```
<HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER">
    <NombreButton text="7" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" />
    <NombreButton text="8" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" />
    <NombreButton text="9" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" />
</HBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `action` and add `id`'s (do not forget fx's xmlns) :

```
<HBox spacing="10" alignment="CENTER" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <Button fx:id="bNumber7" text="7" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" />
    <Button fx:id="bNumber8" text="8" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" />
    <Button fx:id="bNumber9" text="9" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" />
    <Button fx:id="bDivide" text="/" prefWidth="50" font="$FONT" />
</HBox>
```

And then, in your controller :

```
public Calculator {

    @FXML
    private Button bNumber7;

    @FXML
    private Button bNumber8;

    @FXML
    private Button bNumber9;

    private HBox component;

    /**
    * Constructor.
    */
    public void Calculator() {
       // Load your fxml.
       FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResources("YourFxmlPath.fxml"));
       // Set this class as controller of the view.
       loader.setController(this);
       try {
          component = (HBox)loader.load();
       } catch(IOException e) {
          System.out.println("An error occurs trying to load the FXML : "+ e);
       }
    }

    @FXML 
    private void initialize() {
       bNumber7.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
          System.out.println("Clicked on 7 button.");
          // Do your stuff
       });

       // Add listener on other buttons if needed.

       bDivide.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
          System.out.println("Clicked on 7 button.");
          // Do your stuff
       });
    }
}
```